# group_by() level disappear after filter()/mutate()/count() without using ungroup

Tags: r, dplyr

This problem bothers me for the entire day and I don't know why it happens.
The issue is group_by level will disappear after one line of code such as filter(),mutate(), count(), and in order to keep that level, I need to add group_by() everytime after these codes again to keep the group level.
Below I attach an example.

As you can see, if I add group_by after filter, it works fine.

```
data("mtcars")
> mtcars %>% 
+     filter(hp == 110) %>% 
+     group_by(cyl) %>%
+     count(mpg)
  cyl  mpg n
1   6 21.0 2
2   6 21.4 1
```

However, if I use group_by before filter and count the value, it will lose the group by level

```
data("mtcars")
> mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl) %>%
+   filter(hp == 110) %>% 
+   count(mpg)
   mpg n
1 21.0 2
2 21.4 1
```

In order to make it work, I need to change codes to

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl) %>%
+   filter(hp == 110) %>% 
+   group_by(cyl) %>%
+   count(mpg)
  cyl  mpg n
1   6 21.0 2
2   6 21.4 1
```

This method also doesn't work:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>%
+   dplyr::filter(hp == 110) %>% 
+   dplyr::count(mpg)
   mpg n
1 21.0 2
2 21.4 1
```

I am using another PC to run the codes and it works well.

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl) %>%
+   filter(hp == 110) %>% 
+   count(mpg)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [1]
    cyl   mpg     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     6  21       2
2     6  21.4     1
```

I have reinstalled dplyr package many times and this thing keeps happening. I am using version 1.0.2 for dplyr.
Really appreciate if someone can help me about this issue!

**Edit:
The problem is being solved after I update my R version to 4.0.2 (my previous version is 3.6.3). Not sure why dplyr doesn't work properly undr 3.6.3 but at least the problem is being solved for now.**

Comment: check the `.groups` and `.preserve` arguments of functions like `filter` and `summarise` - the recent version of dplyr drops the last level of grouping by default:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html

Comment: Are you using the same version of dplyr on both the PC's ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes I use 1.0.2 for both the PC.

Comment: @CourtesyBus Thanks for the response. I have tried the .preserve already but it still cause the same problem. Also it works well in another PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data("mtcars")
> mtcars %>% 
+   dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>%
+   dplyr::filter(hp == 110) %>% 
+   dplyr::count(mpg)
```

There can be masking problem. Function `filter` is in `dplyr` and `stats` package as well. Same issue was discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/the-function-dplyr-filter-is-masked-by-stats-filter-how-to-change-it/17673). Similar problem occours with `select` function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this in my PC and it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Also note in that context the difference between:

```
data("mtcars")

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
  summarize(
    n=n()
  ) %>%
  mutate(mysum = sum(n))


   
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
 
    cyl  gear     n mysum
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     4     3     1    11
2     4     4     8    11
3     4     5     2    11
4     6     3     2     7
5     6     4     4     7
6     6     5     1     7

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl,gear) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(mysum = sum(n))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   cyl, gear [8]
    cyl  gear     n mysum
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     4     3     1     1
2     4     4     8     8
3     4     5     2     2
4     6     3     2     2
5     6     4     4     4
```

Summarise defaults to dropping the last grouping variable (.groups="drop_last"). And for a funny reason :)
https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/1254802700589555715